# How to scan a full message when making a discord bot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am trying to make a discord bot although I have come across a problem. Here is the default code:

```
    if message.content.startswith('hello'):
```

I want to change that so that it scans the full message instead of just the start.
I have tried variations but have not found anything. Can anyone help me?
Thank you people in advance.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to scan each *line* of the message to see if that particular line starts with the text?

Comment: to check for a custom message in a `str` you can do this `if 'hello' in message.content:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Explanation

`message.content` is a **string variable** on which the **complete message content is saved**. `startswith` is a **python string method** which allows you, to check the **beginning of the string variable** you have given.

## Using `equal to`

With this you can check of the message content is identical to a specific text and you get to this:

```
if message.content == 'hello':
```

## Using `in`

Another solution would be for example to check if 'hello' is somewhere in the message:

```
if 'hello' in message.content:
```

Comment: Thank you guys so much! I could not find this anywhere else. You people fixed my problem. Thank you!